# Webcam is ound by VLC but not found by web browsers

Tags: fedora, thinkpad, camera

I have an x200s ThinkPad with Fedora 30 and an old-fashioned TCM 234282 USB webcam. VLC manages to stream video out of the box, however if I use Jitsi in Firefox or Chromium, the webcam is not found (webcam is enabled in security settings). Cheese can't find it either.

According to the VLC settings, it takes input from `/dev/video0`  and calls the stream  `v4l2://`

Results of `lsusb` :

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 093a:2600 Pixart Imaging, Inc.   
Typhoon Easycam USB 330K (newer)/Typhoon Easycam USB 2.0 VGA 1.3M/Sansun SN-508
```

webcamtests.com says "A web camera was detected". I can only choose "VGA Single chip". If I do so, it says "AbortError: Starting video failed"

I checked the Ubuntu thread as well and nothing worked, neither `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo && sudo modprobe uvcvideo` nor `modprobe uvcvideo`.

I looked in `lsmod` to see what device to activate via `modprobe <name of the device>`, but I don't know what to look for in the output. I don't have a functional key for webcam on my laptop.

Do you have any ideas how I can make it work?

Comment: Please check this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/461657/integrated-webcam-not-detected-after-update-to-14-04

Comment: Does it work with webcamtests.com ? Jitsi/WebRTC is kinda fickle when it comes to "allowed" resolutions or colour formats and I find this website very much capable of identifying problems on this end.